# Javascript: DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-domain, domexception

I am getting **DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules** . Any suggestion how can I resolve the same.

**Sample-Code**

```
function copyStyles(source, target) {
  Array.from(source.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
    let rules
    try {
      rules = styleSheet.cssRules
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
    if (rules) {
      const newStyleEl = source.createElement('style')

      Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach(cssRule => {
        .......
        
      })
      target.head.appendChild(newStyleEl)
    } else if (styleSheet.href) {
      ..........
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the CORS security policy, you can not access the contents of resources loaded from a third-party domain via javascript. This applies to CSS files as well (though not implemented by all browsers yet).

So if one of the `source.styleSheets` is a third-party CSS file, then you will receive this error while trying to access the `cssRules` or `rules` properties of the `stylesheet`

By the way as a solution to what you are trying, instead of creating link tags in the else part, fetch (via xhr or `fetch` API) the `stylesheet.href` and you will have the response in the JS as text which can be appended to a style tag in DOM.

Example

```
fetch(stylesheet.href)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(response => {
      const st = document.createElement('style');
      st.textContent = response;
      document.body.append(st);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your respone ... Do you mind could you please update the anwer if possible.

Comment: Is this `fetch(stylesheet.href)` will be inside `else if` ?

Comment: @Tammy Yes, it should be part of the `else if (styleSheet.href)`

Comment: But I am getting error on `try` `catch` .

Comment: Yup, error will be in try catch (or anywhere you try a `.cssRule` on a third party css stylesheet object.)
Thats the reason why there is `if(rules)` block. So everytime there is a error in the try statement your `rules` variable will be undefined. So it would go to the else where you can fetch the css via xhr and use the response to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid calling cssRules that may be protected via CSP, and instead just add a new stylesheet with whatever rules you want that override the existing ones.

Like this...

```
var S=document.createElement('style');

S.innerHTML='#Menu{background:red;} body{overflow:auto;}';

Frame_ID.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(S);
```

Comment: WebUser really thank you for your time and suggestion but in my case this what I need to reciprocate as a new window.

Comment: In that case get a collection of all stylesheets and do whatever you need with them.